# Typescript Promise duplicate issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, typescript, es6-promise

I have been having a heck of a time getting es6 promises to work with Typescript in a ASP.NET 5 project. I installed the `es6-promise.d.ts` via `tsd install es6-promise`. However, I get errors about Promise being duplicated. When I hover on the Promise declaration in the `es6-promise.d.ts` file, I get the error below (see the blue section ac the bottom of the image). It seems to be conflicting with some typescript definition file from a Microsoft SDK, which is obviously not part of my project.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea on why this might be happening or how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

What version of TypeScript are you using?

Promise is declared in `lib.es6.d.ts`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using TypeScript v1.5.3 and targeting es6, so I didn't need to install the es6-promise because I get it as part of the SDK. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check your `--target` option for `tsc`. If it is equal to `es6` then I think you reference the promise definition twice because [one is part](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts) of `tsc` compiler.

Comment: I see that my response is very similar to the Daniel's one - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5915 :-)